# Finding amount of Iterations in loop

Tags: loops, iteration, formula, equation, counting

I've been stuck on figuring this out for last 3 hours.

I have a for loop that looks like:

```
for(i = 1; i < x^6; i * x)
{
}
```

I know that the amount of times it iterates over the loop is 6. Because it loops through when

- i = 1
- i = x
- i = x^2
- i = x^3
- i = x^4
- i = x^5

But I can't figure out for the life of me how to get that 6 through a mathematical way instead of just counting. Is there an equation or something for finding the iterations in loops. For example in for loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
}
```

The amount it iterates through would be equal to n because the equation increments by 1 each time till it gets to n. What about it if multiplies or divides etc. And would the amount it iterates be equal to its time complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a geometric progression.

The `n`th term of a geometric sequence with initial value `a` and common ratio `r` is `ar^(n-1)`.

In your case, `a = 1` and `r = x`, so the `n`th term is `x^(n-1)`.

Since the largest term in your loop is `x^5`, you get `x^(n-1) = x^5`, hence `n = 6`.